# Thermochemical data for thiocyanatoiron(III) ion

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, enthalpy, reference-request, entropy

I am currently writing a lab report about the formation constant of $\ce{FeSCN^2+}.$ All I could find online was a formation constant at $\pu{25 °C}$ $(890),$ which was 70% higher than the experimentally measured value at $\pu{21.7 °C}$ $(292).$

I was hoping to use van't Hoff's equation to calculate the accepted value at $\pu{21.7 °C},$ and I found enthalpies and entropies of formation for $\ce{Fe^3+(aq)}$ and $\ce{SCN-(aq)},$ but nothing for $\ce{FeSCN^2+},$ so I can't calculate the enthalpy or entropy of reaction.

Does anyone have a credible source for this data?